# Throwing 6 sided cube 12 times. Probability of not getting 6 twice

Tags: probability

Throwing 6 sided cube 12 times.

What is the probability of rolling no more than two 6's?

My thoughts so far:
There are 6 outcomes for each throw, so 6¹² is the total number of outcomes.
(5/6)¹² is the number of outcomes that I don't get a 6.
(5/6)¹⁰ is that I don't get a 6 in 10 throws, so the last 2 don't matter.
Is my thinking correct here, or am I missing something ?
Can someone help me with understanding the solution. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?  Title and body have different questions. Not more than two 6's or not two 6's?

Comment: What is the probability of rolling no more than two sixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling no more than two sixes would mean we either roll no six, $1$ six or we roll $2$ sixes in $12$ times. If random variable $X$ is the number of sixes then we have,

$P(X = 0) \, = (\frac{5}{6})^{12}$

$P(X = 1) \, = {12 \choose 1} \times \frac{1}{6} \times (\frac{5}{6})^{11}$

$P(X = 2) \, = {12 \choose 2} \times (\frac{1}{6})^2 \times (\frac{5}{6})^{10}$

Desired probability $ P (X \leq 2) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + P(X = 2)$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if I should do something like this. But i gave up, because I thought summing all this posibilities won't be correct.

Comment: @MilanPanic think this way. What makes your sample space? $6^{12}$, correct? The sample space $6^{12}$ includes all the combinations including no six, one six, two sixes etc. So you are picking all combinations that are favorable out of $6^{12}$. Is it clear?

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{12}{0}(\frac{1}{6})^0(\frac{5}{6})^{12}+\binom{12}{1}(\frac{1}{6})^1(\frac{5}{6})^{11}+\binom{12}{2}(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{5}{6})^{10}$$

$\binom{12}{0}(\frac{1}{6})^0(\frac{5}{6})^{12}$ is the probability of no any 6

$\binom{12}{1}(\frac{1}{6})^1(\frac{5}{6})^{11}$ is the probability of one 6

$\binom{12}{2}(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{5}{6})^{10}$ is the probability of two 6's

Comment: Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Milan Panic : You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Binomial distribution:

$$P(X=x)={n\choose x}p^x q^{n-x}$$

Where
$$n=\text{Number of trials}\\
x=\text{Number of succeses}\\
p=\text{Probability of succeding in one trial}\\
q=1-p$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand this.